# Does Drupal work with PHP 7?

Tags: 7

I have working development project of Drupal 7 using PHP 5.x. I changed the PHP version to PHP 7 using nginx webserver. It does not work and I have got the following error message:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant
 'MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY' in
 C:\xampp-2\htdocs\d738\includes\database\mysql\database.inc:46 Stack
 trace: #0 C:\xampp-2\htdocs\d738\includes\database\database.inc(1689):
 DatabaseConnection_mysql->__construct(Array) #1
 C:\xampp-2\htdocs\d738\includes\database\database.inc(1479):
 Database::openConnection('default', 'default') #2
 C:\xampp-2\htdocs\d738\includes\database\database.inc(2570):
 Database::getConnection() #3
 C:\xampp-2\htdocs\d738\includes\cache.inc(348):
 db_escape_table('cache_bootstrap') #4
 C:\xampp-2\htdocs\d738\includes\cache.inc(329):
 DrupalDatabaseCache->getMultiple(Array) #5
 C:\xampp-2\htdocs\d738\includes\cache.inc(56):
 DrupalDatabaseCache->get('module_implemen...') #6
 C:\xampp-2\htdocs\d738\includes\module.inc(723):
 cache_get('module_implemen...', 'cache_bootstrap') #7
 C:\xampp-2\htdocs\d738\includes\module.inc(892):
 module_implements('system_theme_in...') #8
 C:\xampp-2\htdocs\d738\modules\system\system.module(2502):
 module_invoke_all('system_theme in
 C:\xampp-2\htdocs\d738\includes\database\mysql\database.inc on line 46
```

This error means that Drupal 7 is using obsoleted MySQL functions and it is not support with PHP any more!

However, I don't think Drupal still uses this obsoleted PHP extension. So I have a strange error as I think!

Comment: What is the question? Are you looking for a way to fix this, or a confirmation that Drupal doesn't work with PHP 7?

Comment: Indeed, I wanted both, I found the error message strange. it talks about `mysql_` the obsoleted extension

Comment: Actually, the class is `DatabaseConnection_mysql`, a Drupal class.

Comment: There is an open core issue on PHP 7 support: https://www.drupal.org/node/2454439

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search and edit your **php.ini** file, you must search this line:

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

remove the `;` and save the file, then restart your webserver.

Comment: Oh yes, the `phpinfo()` output tricked me! However, just as my case, when use non global installation of PHP i.e not have path environment value, you have to uncomment the `extension_dir` directive.

Comment: @sємsєм I work in GNU/Linux and I've never had to modify the extension_dir

Comment: I did this and am still getting the "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY'"